# Bitwise operation of a number goes wrong or not

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

Output of ~43 in c++ is -44 but I calculate that 212.

In c++, I'm just calculating ~43 and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char hjg = 43;
    cout << ~hjg;
        //43 -> 0010 1011
        //212 -> 1101 0100
}
```

And the output is `-44`. But when I calculate it in my mobile calculator, I get 212.

My first question is why the output is negative?

And second is why the output is `-44`
instead `212`?

Comment: Do you know how two's complement works, and what it is? Are you familiar with integer promotion rules in C++? Have you noticed that if you add 43 to 212 you get 255 (and adding 44 gets you 256)? Does anything about this number strike you odd, for some reason?

Comment: `~hjg` is the same as `~static_cast<int>(hjg)`.  Perhaps you wanted `+static_cast<char>(~hjg)`, or as `((~hjg) & 0xFF)`.  The `+` makes it output as a value, rather than interpreted as a char.

Comment: Change `char` to `uint8_t` and see the difference

Comment: @user4581301 no, because the type is `int` not `char` anymore

Comment: right! Did math on it!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just know how one's complement works, not two's complement. And I expect that NOT used for one's complement

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `char` is being promoted to `int`. In hex its value is 0x2b
2. `~` is being applied to `int` 0x2b and the result is `0xffffffd4` (if your implementation uses 32bits integers)
3. `0xffffffd4` in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is `-44` and this value is printed.

I would encourage you to experiment yourself like: https://godbolt.org/z/3Ecf4YrWf

BTW if you assign `char` (assuming signed chars) with `1101 0100` it will also hold `-44`.